# How to implement a flipflop logic for buy/ sell signals using NaNs and fillnas in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two series of buy and sell signals in my python dataframe. The logic is that of a flipflop that I am trying to implement - I can sell only after I buy and I cannot buy before I have already sold. So basically, 1 and -1 have to occur only after they have already occured.

```
buy      = [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0]
sell     = [ 0,  0,  0, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0]
expected = [ 0,  0,  0,  1, -1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0]
```

How can I do this without a for loop? Possibly with vectors + fillna + NaN values or merge?

Comment: Would be good to understand, if this is even possible without a for loop! If not, what would be the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: First create a mapping: `[ [(0,0), 0], [(1,0), 1], ...]` etc. If you cannot find one, then creating a function will be impossible. For example, compare column 7 and column 8. These two are different. How do you plan to find "expected" if the same inputs give different outputs?

Comment: Mapping wouldn't be possible because it needs "in-memory" of what happened last from the start of the series/ before that point in the series.